# how do I update user profile property in SharePoint 2013

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property, ssom

We are using sp2013.

There is a custom user profile property with name:  MyProperty (boolean).

The property cannot be edited by user.

I want to update the property value for current user on an application page on click of a button.

Since the property cannot be edited by user, should RWEP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier approach is to allow the user to update the property and just hide the value from their edit page. Then you don't need RWEP. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes I have gone ahead with this method.

Comment: Can I get an answer click from you?

Answer (score 2):

Run with Elevated privileges runs the Code in System Account/App pool account. So you will have to make sure that App pool account has "**Manage Profile Permission**" rights to the User Profile Service. Follow below steps:
Go to Central Admin-->Choose **Application Management** --> **Manage Service Applications**-->
Select the **User Profile Service Application** (do not open the service application).
Click Administrators in the ribbon on top -->Add the App pool account and set the Manage Profiles permission. See this blog for [Granting permission to UPS](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/granting-permissions-user-profile-service-application-powershell/).

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
       {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername"))//change the hardcoded URL to suit your requirement
        {
            SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            UserProfileManager userProfileMgr = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
            UserProfile user = userProfileMgr.GetUserProfile(@'domain\username');
            user["propertyName"]  = "newValue";
            user.Commit();


        }
    });
```

See this [MSDN Blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163142%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for Working with UPS using Server Object Model.

Comment: Can you provide some code

Comment: @variable edited my answer

Comment: The system acc has full control, that is what RWEP does right? Then why do I have to set the right to apppool acc.?

Comment: also suppose I do not use RWEP. Then which user do I give rights to?

Comment: App pool account is the site col admin or the web app admin?

Comment: Error: Property Not Editable: This property can only be modified by an administrator.

Comment: You have to provide some user (preferably the app pool account)administrator privileges to the User profile service and run the code in that user's context. I have added a link to a blog on how to do it.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the user profile app service and can see that my site col as well as web app administrator is having rights to manage permissions.

Comment: @variable Can you post the User profile property settings to the question. Also see this http://msscorner.de/en/2011/10/18/userprofile-manager-eigenschaft-kann-nicht-bearbeitet-werden-diese-eigenschaft-kann-nur-von-einem-administrator-geandert-werden/

Comment: If I change the setting to allow user to edit, then, remove RWEP, and use web.allowunsafeupdates then it works. Yes I checked that link and it does not conflict.

Comment: Can you tell me if it is OK to set 'allow user to edit' under user profile property setting?? But, I donot want user to manually change this setting. Presently my settings are Policy setting: Required; default privacy setting: Only Me; User cannot override; allow user to edit this value.

Comment: ok you have to set it as this :Default privacy settings-->Everyone.  uncheck user can override --> check Do not allow user to edit this value.

Comment: dont I have to create new SPWeb object within RWEP? That is one of the rules of RWEP isnt it?

Comment: no you don't need SPWeb object to update user profile.

Comment: What is meaning of setting default privacy setting :everyone?

Comment: Anyways I get same error: Property Not Editable: This property can only be modified by an administrator. Looks like I have to set 'allow user to edit it'.